Why do I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: picobel`?
I am building a webpage with an audio player:
...
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>


I want to replace it with this fancy player called Picobel.
The documentation says I can use it the old-fashioned way:
<!-- Load Picobel -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='picobel.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    picobel();
</script>

Only it's an NPM package and I'm not sure where to find picobel.min.js
There is a file called ode_modules/picobel/legacy/picobel.legacy.min.js
But when I point my webpage to that I get the error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: picobel.
How do I use Picobel without resorting to Yarn/NPM?

If you don't want to use the package management tools that the implementor of the package chose, you'll have to wrangle the installation yourself. Why don't you want to use the package management tools necessary?

Also the documentation for that package tells you exactly what it is you need if you want to skip the package manager. What didn't work in that process?

@Pointy Where is the bundled script with the name picobel.min.js? I didn't find it, too. The problem is described in the question. "Only it's an NPM package and I'm not sure where to find picobel.min.js. There is a file called ode_modules/picobel/legacy/picobel.legacy.min.js"

It looks like a bug in the documentation or the documentation is incomplete. Why didn't you create an issue? https://github.com/tomhazledine/picobel/issues

It's missing from the documentation, but if you look in the Github repository for that project, you'll find them here. And as with most public packages, it's also available through the most common CDN hosts: jsDelivr for example

@blex No, I can't find picobel.min.js there.

@jabaa it's not called ".min", but the files suffixed with a version number are minified, as desired

@blex That's what I mean with bug in the documentation. The documentation isn't correct.
